# determining length, slope, and other measurements of an SVG line segment

Tags: javascript, svg

I'd like to use JavaScript to determine the length, slope, and other measurements of an existing SVG line segment (in screen pixels). I've been trying to use the [jquery-svg](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) plugin, but haven't had any luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With more searching, I found some JavaScript methods that should do the job:

**[getTotalLength()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff972191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

`document.getElementById("segment-line-c2200").getTotalLength()`

returns 205.11094665527344

**[getBBox()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff972173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

`document.getElementById("segment-line-c2200").getBBox()`

returns

```
SVGRect
  height: 32.8560791015625
  width: 202.4622802734375
  x: 1617.7255859375
  y: 2013.96435546875
  __proto__: SVGRect
```